# How to reduce the size of the resultant video while merging an audio and a video using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, audio, merge, ffmpeg, size

1) **My Video is just 151kb with the following properties**: 
(*ffmpeg.exe -i room3159_0.flv* )

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 0.33 (1/3)
Input #0, flv, from 'room3159_0.flv':
  Metadata:
    width           : 940
    height          : 639
    framerate       : 1
    videocodecid    : 3
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    metadatacreator : Video Encoder 1.0 innowhite.com
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flashsv, bgr24, 940x639, 0.33 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc

2) **My Audio is just 1.33MB with the following properties:** (ffmpeg.exe -i abc111.mp3) ::::

[mp3 @ 000000000031A290]max_analyze_duration reached
[mp3 @ 000000000031A290]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'abc111.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf52.61.0
  Duration: 00:05:48.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 32 kb/s

3) ***On merging the above two files (audio & video), what is the least sized video that i can achieve?*** *while atleast maintaining the quality of the video.

i am getting a video with a whopping size of 19MB with the following command:

ffmpeg.exe -i room3159_0.flv -i abc111.mp3 -target ntsc-dvd -r 10 -b 150 -sameq -vcodec c
opy VidAud.mpg          (was trying to use the various parameters)

Thanks in advance!

RS

Answer (score 1):

From the parameters it seems like you are encoding to MPEG2 for NTSC dvd.  It has a defined minimum bitrate, [check this link on doom9 archives](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-87961.html).

Your audio has 5 minutes.  So, your resulting mpg will have 5 minutes, and if it's 2000mbit (which is minimum for the DVD), go figure the rest...

Comment: the link was quite helpful. But are you aware of any way that can reduce the size of the resultant video? im not too particular about using mpeg or dvd quality.. 
PS: 151kb + 1.33mb = 19mb is not good at all.

Comment: how does that help? could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I did - you are using the profile that is used to create DVD compatible MPEG files.  DVD has MINIMUM bitrate that is defined for it, which is 2mbit.  So, if you use this command line switch, you effectively set the bitrate to 2mbit.